# extension method not updating itself

Tags: c#, extension-methods

Given the following object and its extension:

```
public class MyObj
{
    string var1 = "100";
    string var2 = "200";
}

public static void DoSomething(this MyObj myobj)
{
    myobj = new MyObj()
    myobj.var1 = "100000";
    myobj.var2 = "200000";
}
```

Note the extension method instantiates a new instance and assigns it to itself. When I do this however, my object is not actually updated as expected. It still contains the old variable values and is left untouched.

```
MyObj myobj = new MyObj();
myobj.DoSomething();

//myobj.var1 is still 100, but expected it to be 100000;
//myobj.var1 is still 200, but expected it to be 200000;
```

How do I get my object to update as expected - can this be done?

Comment: Please explain the down vote.

Comment: The code that you posted won't even compile.  Provide an example that can actually reproduce the problem you describe.

Comment: Thats because its psedo code? clearly the princple was sound enough for everyone else to understand the question.

Comment: nonsense - did you make that rule up? As long as people get the concept (and they are) whats the problem.

Comment: I agree with Servy that you use real code as much as possible. It wasn't that much work, as you see in my edit.

Comment: No, I did not make that up.  It's an explicit requirement that if you're showing code, it should be able to reproduce the problem you're describing.

Comment: @PatrickHofman It is specifically prohibited to edit someone else's question to change the code to try to fix problems with it.

Comment: @PatrickHofman please don't rollback my edit.  Why would you?

Comment: Servy - are you trying to help, or just be difficult.

Comment: @PatrickHofman http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260245/when-should-i-make-edits-to-code

Comment: @MarzSocks I'm trying to get you to post an appropriate question.  Why are you so opposed to actually posting code that actually reproduces your own problem?

Comment: Not opposed to it - but I dont think it deserves a down vote, since EVERYONE understood the concept. And pseudocode is a legitimate teaching mechanism (they use it in university to explain concepts).. anyhow, I updated it just for you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can't assign another instance to itself from an extension method. You are just changing the reference to the local variable `myobj`.

You *can* do this from a static method with `ref`:

```
public static void DoSomething(ref MyObj myobj)
{
    myobj = new MyObj()
    myobj.var1 = 100000;
    myobj.var2 = 200000;
}
```

Usage:

```
MyObj myobj = null;
DoSomething(ref myobj);
// myobj is set here
```

Comment: thanks for the response. You get the answer because you explained that "you cant assign another instance to itself". I still dont understand why yet - but its enough knowledge to pursue other approaches. :)

Comment: Read up on [variable scope](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa691132(v=vs.71).aspx).

Comment: Thanks - oh and please consider upvoting me to counter the downvote if you think the question is legitimate enough.

Answer (score 1):

You could just create a new object with a constructor like this.

```
MyObj(int x, int y)
{
    var1 = x;
    var2 = y;
}
```

and call like:

```
MyObj myobj = new MyObj(100,200);
```

Comment: @PatrickHofman That's why this answer is suggesting that he not use an extension method; it's suggesting he use a constructor, which is almost certainly what *should* be used for such a situation.

Comment: Ah, my bad, for reason had a brain fart and didn't read the 'extension' part. Will delete as your answer is correct and no need for double copies of answers.

Comment: Okay, if that is the answer I am okay with it @Servy

Comment: This is actually the best option. Extension methods are not meant for this.

Answer (score 1):

Another way to go if you want to keep the extension method:

```
public static MyObj DoSomething(this MyObj myobj)
{
    myobj = new MyObj()
    myobj.var1 = "100000";
    myobj.var2 = "200000";

    return myobj;
}
```

And you use it like so

```
MyObj myobj = new MyObj();
myobj = myobj.DoSomething();
```

Note that if your `DoSomething` method is just used to reset the object, you might as well use a constructor.